# Expectation of number of hits by a brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, stopping-time

If we denote $\tau_i$ the sequence of stopping times defined by:
$\tau_i = \inf(t>\tau_{i-1} : |B(t)-B(\tau_{i-1})| > a)$, $\tau_0=0$.

If we denote N the number of stopping times below T.

What is the expectation of N (i.e. the average number of stopping times below T)?